# How to send an JSON array to another method

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, arraylist

I am fetching an JSON response from an API. 
I should return those JSON response to another method with selected fields

Here I am fetching all the JSON response and putting it to an JSONArray which I should return to another method.

How to fetch both String and Long returning fields and put it into an JSON array and return it to another method

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("/2.0/clusters/list");
request.addHeader("Authorization", "bearerToken");
request.addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");


HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
System.out.println("Response Code:" +
        response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

System.out.println("Gather Details\n");

JSONObject cluster = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray clusterJsonArray = cluster.getJSONArray("clusters");

for (int i = 0; i < clusterJsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject iteratingObj = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = iteratingObj.get("id").toString();
    String time = iteratingObj.get("time").toString();

    System.out.println("Id:" + id + "time:" + time + "\n");

    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int p = 0; p < clusterJsonArray.length(); p++) {
        strList.add(clusterJsonArray.getJSONObject(p).getString("id"));
        strList.add(clusterJsonArray.getJSONObject(p).getString("time"));
    }

    System.out.println("Arr:" + strList);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        System.out.println("Failed HTTPresponse" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + "" + json);
    }
}
```

Help me out to send the response with selected fields to other method in which that JSONarray should take both String and Long values and store it in one varible of JSONArray.

Here is the incoming JSON:

```
"clusters": [ 
{ "id": "0411-0089ki", "driver": { }, "start_timestamp": 1568952332573, },
```

Here  **JSONObject["time"] not a string**  is the error i am facing when i am putting it to JSONArray

Comment: Please format your code properly. you have missing `}`.

Comment: Please add incoming json.

Comment: This is an Example JSON response I am getting.

```


"clusters": [
        {
            "id": "0411-0089ki",
            "driver": {                
                },
    "start_timestamp": 1568952332573,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The intention of the above code you mentioned is not clear. But,

> Here JSONObject["time"] not a string is the error i am facing when i
>   am putting it to JSONArray

You can use:

```
long time = iteratingObj.getLong("start_timestamp");
```

But you do not use the local variables of `id` and `time` in anywhere.

I think the logic is incorrect in the code that you put in the question. Please double check the logic for these 2 loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < clusterJsonArray.length(); i++) {

for (int p = 0; p < clusterJsonArray.length(); p++) {
```